# Should I use Magnet Wire as a conductor in this experiment?

Tags: signal, wire, interference

I need to run a few wires from a [HMC5883L compass sensor](http://www51.honeywell.com/aero/common/documents/myaerospacecatalog-documents/Defense_Brochures-documents/HMC5883L_3-Axis_Digital_Compass_IC.pdf) to a micro-controller to process the data. Can I use magnet wire to carry the signals from the sensor to the micro-controller or would the signals between the wires interfere with each other?

There are about 5 or 6 individual wires running from the sensor to the micro-controller. Is this a bad idea or should I get some thicker wire?

The team is just worried that the signals might cross over. This is the last part of the experiment that we need to do and we just want to know if the wire will hold up.

Comment: What is the sensor?

Comment: I'm sorry. Its a HMC5883L compass.

Comment: @Matt better to edit the question to add information.

Answer (score 2):

Magnet wire is no different that normal wire except insulation is very thin and it's prone to scratching and exposing conductor causing short circuits. If you can live with that, I don't see why not.

Comment: Thank you. I was just concerned that the signals would get mixed up. I added an extra layer of enamel so scratching does not worry me that much.

Comment: Really depends on what kind of sensor. If it has special shielding requirements, then obviously this is not correct choice.

Comment: It's a small sensor that is just being used to measure the magnetic flux in a coil.

Comment: Digital signals aren't at risk. If it's an active component, there's no need to worry.